# text width inApplicationBarIconButton

Tags: windows-phone-7

I use the next:

```
<shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="icon.png" Click="Near_Click"
                                        Text="Some_long_word" />
```

and text is trimmed. How can I fix it?

Comment: `ApplicationBarIconButton.Text` has length limit and it cannot be fixed. This is how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't fix it.  You can't have a long text size in the applicationBarIconButton.